# best practice to make a loop faster - is Multithreading an option?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, api, url

I call a Api Service with an index in the URL; for example the last index is: 420.555. I do this:

```
for(int i =0; i <= 420555;i++){
  url = new URl("https://someURL/"+ i);
  read the json with BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( url.openStream(), "UTF-8" ) )) {

   create object from json
   save the result to my DB
}
```

the performance is very bad.

( sure, there are many entries to save in my DB but it needs over 6 hrs and crashed because memory full in the JAVA VM )

Do you have any Idea, how can i do this faster ?

If you need the full code, i can post it. but i think the for loop is the problem...

My idea was, to use Multithreading, but i have never worked befor and i'm not sure if it's best practice for this case.

When multithreading is best practice, can you give me an example for this case?

Comment: Multithreading won't solve your memory problem.

Comment: For the memory issue, I might try closing the BufferedReader at the end of each loop. As for time... you're making >400k web socket requests. What's your download speed?

Comment: i didn't search a answer for my memory problem first. I want to it faster at first. The memory i can increase...

my download speed is ca. 200k

Comment: Do you need to fetch data in a particular order ?

Answer (score 5):

Your code does:

- fetch the content from a URL as json
- do some stuff, to then save a result into a database

It does that in sequence.

So, yes, of course, doing those loop bodies in parallel should cut down overall execution time. It will not help on memory issues. As the comments are pointing out, that problem is more likely caused by bugs in your code (for example by not closing resources properly).

Of course, that introduces new kinds of problems; such as dealing with connection pools for DB access.

In order to add "more than one thread"; the straight forward approach would be to submit tasks into an ExecutorService - see [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) for example.

Finally: the first real answer is to step back. It seems that already the task at hand is **hard** for you to get right! Adding more complexity might help with certain problems; but you should *absolutely* first ensure that your code is fully correct and working in "sequential mode" before adding the more-than-one-thread thing. Otherwise, you will run into other problems, quickly, in a less deterministic but harder to debug way.

The second real answer is: making 400K requests is **never** a good idea. Not in sequence, not in parallel. A real world solution would be to step back, and change that API and allow for **bulk** reads for example. Don't download 400K objects in 400K requests. Make 100 requests and download 4K objects each time for example.

Long story short: your *real* problem is the design of that API you are using. Unless you change that, you are not solving your problem but fighting symptoms.

Comment: i can't change the API. It's not my API. Only i need the Data from there.

Comment: As said: then there isn't too much that you can do; besides A) fixing your current code; and when that works, B) use an executor service to make requests in parallel. But as said: those 400K network requests translate to burn enormous amounts of resources.

Comment: i have add my code on github gist:
https://gist.github.com/EikeBierman/fde05dde2e09d6167f76c41fe41828f1

Answer (score 2):

Yes doing your For in parallel manner makes things faster. Here is an example for multi-threading solution:

```
//set THREADS_COUNT for controlling concurrency level
int THREADS_COUNT=8;

//make a shared repository for your URLs
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> indexRepository=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i< 420555;i++)
    indexRepository.add(i);

// Define a ExecutorService which providing us multiple threads
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS_COUNT);

//create multiple tasks (the count is the same as our threads)
for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_COUNT; i++)
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(!indexRepository.isEmpty()){
                url = new URl("https://someURL/"+ indexRepository.remove());
                //read the json with BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( url.openStream(), "UTF-8" ) )) {
                //create object from json
                //save the result to my DB
            }
        }
    });

executor.shutdown();

// Wait until all threads are finish
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

}
System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");
```

Note that, How to work with the database can also affect the performance significantly. Using batch insert or using proper transactions can improve your performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confused, but looking your code, first of all closes the streans for each interaction:

```
String url = "https://someURL/%d";
        for(int i =0; i <= 420555;i++){
            try (InputStreamReader fis = new InputStreamReader(new URL(String.format("https://someURL/",i)).openStream(), "UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fis)) {
                // do the job
            }
        }
```

Comment: This does not answer to the question.

Comment: If you read the question he ask "BEST PRACTICE...", it is a best practice open streams and bufferedereaders and keep them opened? I think NOT, and my post yes, answer the question, or part of it, of course, there are many other tecniques to do that maybe can increase the performanse, call the rest by batch and so on.

Comment: More, the JVM crash is probably caused by the opened streams or by the rest of the code thats ommited.

Comment: AFAIK, using `try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( allmoviesUrl.openStream(), "UTF-8" ) ))` closes the `reader`, who in turn closes the `InputStreamReader`, who in turn closes the `InputStream`. Other than that, I agree that parallelization of broken code only makes it crash faster. :D Let's call it `fail-fast`. :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do it faster by using [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--)

Use below API if you are using java-8

```
public static ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool()
```

> Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all available processors as its target parallelism level.

If you are not using java 8, use

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
```

and set number of threads as available processors

```
nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get data required from external API, you can only make it parallel to increase performance.

You can separate your range into smaller (e.g. [1-20], [21 - 40], ...) then create ExecutorService with some pool size and process each chunk in parallel.

It will increase performance of your programm, but not to much. Also it depends on CPU of your machine.

Solution of GhostCat is right, but I proposed alternative variant. If you can't get more data than do 400K requests - it's only one way to increase performance for getting data.

Answer (score 0):

one more bottleneck what I am seeing is saving db.If do the saving one by one then performance will be low as it involve I/O .One of better approach will be separate out reader and writer .

Reader :Down load chunk by chunk for an example batch size 500.

Writer:save to db with batch size 500.

If make compartmentalization then it will be easily scallable as per requirement you can increase reader thread and writer thread .or one thread will do read/write one chunk i.e 500.